# Touchpad speed is too slow even on max

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I really want to know how to increase pointer speed when I'm using the touchpad. It just seems to be too slow even on max setting and I tried to configure via dconf-editor but I can't change it more than 1.0. xinput didn't work also.

Thank you.